# Poisson point process - Convergence

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

**Preliminary:** If $N_{\lambda}(t)$ is a random variable representing the number of arrivals in time interval $[0,t]$, for a Poisson point process with a fixed rate $\lambda$, then
$$\frac{N_{\lambda}(t)}{t}\xrightarrow{a.s}\lambda$$

Here, $N_{\lambda}(t)$ corresponds to a family of Poisson point process with fixed rate $\lambda$. Note that $N_{\lambda_1}(t)$ and $N_{\lambda_2}(t)$ are independent, for any $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$.

**Problem:**

> Does the following hold? How can we prove it?
>   $$\frac{N_{(1/\sqrt{t})}(t)}{\sqrt{t}}\xrightarrow{a.s}1$$

My attemp: If we assume $S_n$ is the $n^{th}$ time of arrival, then

$$\frac{\sqrt{t}N_{(1/\sqrt{t})}(t)}{S_{N_{(1/\sqrt{t})}(t)+1}}<\frac{N_{(1/\sqrt{t})}(t)}{\sqrt{t}}<\frac{\sqrt{t} N_{(1/\sqrt{t})}(t)}{S_{N_{(1/\sqrt{t})}(t)}}$$

I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: Do you mean one process whose rate decays over time? Or do you mean a parametrized family of processes whose rates are each fixed? In the latter case an a.s. result does not really make sense. You could speak of a distributional result though.

Comment: I mean the latter. Can you please clarify the answer?

Comment: If you mean the latter, then you have r.v.s with mean $1$ and variance $1/\sqrt{t}$ so they converge to $1$ in distribution (and therefore, automatically, in probability). But it is not clear how such a thing should be defined on one probability space.

Comment: The problem here is that $\{N(t) : t\in\mathbb R_+\}$ is not a stochastic process in the usual sense (with $N(t)$ a real-valued random variable for each $t$), but instead each $N(t)$ is itself a stochastic process $N(t)=\{N(t)(x) : x\in\mathbb R_+\}$. So it is not clear how to even make sense of a statement, e.g. $$\mathbb P(|N(t)/\sqrt t -1|<\varepsilon).$$

Comment: @Math1000 Thanks for your comment. For the almost sure convergence, we need to prove $\mathbb{P}(\lim_{t \to \infty} N(t)/\sqrt{t}=1)=1$. But the one that you said implies on the convergence in the probability. Also, I didn't understand why $N(t)$ is not a stochastic process and why the above statement does not make sense?

Comment: Do you know anything about the distribution of the inter-arrival times?

Comment: Yes, for a Poisson point process, the distribution of inter-arrivals are exponential, $\lambda e^(- \lambda x) $

Comment: This is true for a homogeneous PP. Here the process is non-homogeneous   with mean $\Lambda(A)=\int _A\lambda(x)dx$

Comment: No, this is homogeneous

Comment: Homogeneous is when $\lambda(t)=\lambda$,  independent of  $t$, $\Lambda([0,t])=\lambda\cdot t$. Here,  $\lambda(t)=1/\sqrt(t)$

Comment: @theoGR Note that it does not mean a one process whose rate $\lambda$ decays over time, but it is a parametrized family of processes whose rates are each fixed. So, this is a homogeneous Poisson point process.

Comment: Offering a bounty should not be a substitute for making one's question understandable but... It seems that one is actually considering a family $(N_t)_t$ of Poisson processes $(N_t(s))_s$ such that each $N_t$ has intensity $1/\sqrt{t}$, and that one asks to prove that $$\frac{N_t(t)}{\sqrt{t}}\to1$$ almost surely, when $t\to\infty$. Naturally, each $N_t(t)$ is Poisson with mean $\sqrt{t}$, and this goes in the right direction, but one should probably add some strong hypothesis about the dependence of the various processes $N_t$ when $t$ varies, before any positive answer can emerge.

Comment: (cont'd) For example, one realisation of $(N_t)$ could be that $$N_t(s)=N_1(s/\sqrt{t})$$ for every positive $(s,t)$. Then the answer is obviously, yes, $N_t(t)/\sqrt{t}\to1$ almost surely, since, for every $t$, $$N_t(t)=N_1(\sqrt{t}).$$ But one could also decide that the processes $(N_t)$ are independent, or some more complicated stochastic dependence structure, and now the result is not guaranteed anymore.

Comment: @Did Thanks a lot. I tried as much as I could to clarify the question, and this is not true that I didn't use a bounty as a substitute for making it understandable.

Comment: Whatever. What is your question?

Comment: @Did I cleaned up the problem statement so as to make it clear. Thanks.

Comment: Quote: `one should probably add some strong hypothesis about the dependence of the various processes Nt when t varies, before any positive answer can emerge`. As it is, the question should be closed.

Comment: @Did $N_{\lambda_1}(t)$ and $N_{\lambda_2}(t)$ are independent, for any  $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$ . Is is still not clear?

Comment: Then the result does not hold. For example, $N_{1/\sqrt{t}}(t)=0$ for unbounded values of $t$, almost surely.

Comment: Why? Can you write it in the answer section, with more details, provide me an answer so that I can give you the bounty?